# Unable to compile JDK 17 using Maven 3.8: error: module jdk.compiler does not "opens com.sun.tools.javac.processing" to unnamed module

Tags: java, maven, lombok, java-17

I am trying to compile an existing Spring Boot project using JDK 17 and Maven 3.8.4 and I keep getting this error.

> Unable to make field private
> com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors
> com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoveredProcs
> accessible: module jdk.compiler does not "opens
> com.sun.tools.javac.processing" to unnamed module @521e3470

The problem also occurs with older versions of Maven like 3.6.  It also happens with JDK 16.  It does not matter what version of Java is configured in the pom.xml via the `java.version`, `maven.compiler.source`, and `maven.compiler.target`.  only the JDK version being used to do the compiling... displayed in the `mvn -v` command.

The project compiles fine using JDK 15.  The error happens immediately when compiling starts, right after the INFO message stating how many classes are being compiled.  Happens in both my Windows laptop and Ubuntu CI server.

Any ideas what this could be?

EDIT:  adding more of the POM file.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>15</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    <ch.qos.logback.version>1.2.3</ch.qos.logback.version>
</properties>
```

EDIT:  i also use Lombok

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

EDIT:  I dont think this is the same question as the other one because I searched by error msg, and that other question never popped up in the results. To arrive to that question, you need to know that the error is related to Lombok, aka you already need to know the reason for the error. The error gives no clue to Lombok being the culprit.

Comment: Please show your pom file also add as much information as possible...exact Maven version. best would be an example project...also how you call Maven?

Comment: @khmarbaise the Maven version is in the title.  I executed it using `mvn compile`.

Comment: Do you use lombok?

Comment: Oh yeah I do.  You mighbt be on to something.  let me upgrade it.  I'll post my lombok version.

Comment: @khmarbaise upgrading to 1.18.20 fixed it.  Want to throw up an answer and I'll mark it correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is the usage of lombok project which in this case being used not the most recent version.